# Georeferencing using GDAL geotransform top left corner coordinates

Tags: gdal, georeferencing

Following [this stack exchange example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140502/trying-to-build-world-file-for-images-based-off-extent-rectangle-generated-from) by kflaw, and other examples of the use of geotrasform I am trying to georeference images using pre-computed extent rectangles. However, I am also struggling to correctly position the top left corner. Currently the level of offset increases with capture angle (from north).

[image: large offset]

Where the capture angle is small, the level of offset is minimal:

[image: small offset]

What is the correct method for determining the top left coordinates? are they pre or post rotation?

```
# import sys
# print(sys.path)
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import math

# Camera parameters (constants)
sensorWidth = 36
focalLength = 34.2
imageWidth = 8688
imageHeight = 5792

# Dict of test images
images = {
    # '20180319_091011_029A7639':{ #1
    #   'easting': 1580650.51,
    #   'northing': 5231861.27,
    #   'angle': 105.49,
    #   'altitude': 796
    #   },
    '20180319_092454_029A7649':{ #12
        'easting': 1575143.35,
        'northing': 5224588.46,
        'angle': 346.8,
        'altitude': 715.6,
        'width': 753.31,
        'height': 502.18
    },
    # '20180319_102352_029A7720':{ #83
    #   'easting': 1578520,
    #   'northing': 5212668.253,
    #   'angle': 2.24,
    #   'altitude' : 381.1
    # }
}

# Selected image
image = '20180319_092454_029A7649'

# Set the source and output paths and filenames
src_filename = image+'.tif'
dst_filename = image+'_ref.tif'

# Get the x and y coordinates of the centroid
x = images[image]['easting']
y = images[image]['northing']

# Get the flight vector
inputAngle = images[image]['angle']

# # Compute the GSD as a function of height, image size and camera specifications
# cellSize = ((sensorWidth * images[image]['altitude'] * 100) / (focalLength * imageWidth)) / 100
# print('GSD',cellSize)

cellSizeX =  (images[image]['width']) / imageWidth 
cellSizeY = (images[image]['height']) / imageHeight


# Work out the projected dimensions of the image
width = cellSizeX * imageWidth
height = cellSizeY * imageHeight

# Calculate the x and y scale and skew
angleRadians = math.radians(inputAngle)
scalex = cellSizeX * math.cos(angleRadians)
skewx = -cellSizeX * math.sin(angleRadians)
skewy = -cellSizeY * math.sin(angleRadians)
scaley = -cellSizeY * math.cos(angleRadians)

# Find the coordinates of the upper left corner of the image
upperLeftX = x - width / 2
upperLeftY = y + height / 2
# upperLeftVal = RotateXY(upperLeftX,upperLeftY,x,y,inputAngle)

# Opens source dataset
src_ds = gdal.Open(src_filename)
format = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)

# Open destination dataset
dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(dst_filename, src_ds, 0)

# Specify raster location through geotransform array
gt = [upperLeftX, scalex, skewx, upperLeftY, skewy, scaley]

# Set location
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(gt)

# Get raster projection
epsg = 2193
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)
dest_wkt = srs.ExportToWkt()

# Set projection
dst_ds.SetProjection(dest_wkt)

# Close the files
dst_ds = None
src_ds = None
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to correctly derive the top left corner coordinates to remove the offset in the resulting transformed image

Comment: Where do you get these `# Get the x and y coordinates of the centroid
x = images[image]['easting']
y = images[image]['northing']`?

Comment: From the images dictionary near the start of the script, containing the values from a few test scenes.   `'20180319_092454_029A7649':{
        'easting': 1575143.35,
        'northing': 5224588.46, 'angle': 346.8,
        'altitude': 715.6,
        'width': 753.31,
        'height': 502.18
    },`